# How to make a space between buttons in bootstrap using ml-auto?

Tags: c#, html, bootstrap-4

I have two seperated buttons that have created, but they closely packed to another there is no space in between i have tried to use ml-auto. There is not much difference on the UI side and need some help around it.

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 ml-auto">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
            Start New Course
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 ml-auto">
        <a class="btn btn-large btn-success" id="viewCourse" href="@Url.Action("ViewCourses", "Home")">View Grades</a>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#ViewCourses').on('click', function (e) {});
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't figure exactly what you need. I suggest you try to replicate your issue in a code sharing tool like https://codepen.io/pen/ and then maybe we can try to help. Cheers!

Comment: @Peter i want to create a space in between the two buttons they are closely to each other hope make sense.

Comment: Buttons should sit one besides another or one on top of each other? The code that wraps these buttons should also be posted, could be helpful.

Comment: @Peter ok maybe English not my first language, the first button must allow spaces in between the second one(View Course) not too close to each other is not looking good for user experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I think both of your buttons need to sit inside a `.row` element. Right now they are on different rows. Then you can apply a class like `.mr-2` (margin right of 2 units, or increase the number if you want more) to the first button wrapper. Then you will have some spacing between your buttons.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-3 mr-2">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
         Start New Course
       </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <a class="btn btn-large btn-success" id="viewCourse" href="@Url.Action("ViewCourses", "Home")">View Grades</a>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#ViewCourses').on('click', function (e) {});
      </script>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see a working solution here: https://codepen.io/razvan-tudosa/pen/YzqvQVm

More info about how to space stuff you can find in the twitter bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/spacing/

Comment: thanks mate. it does accomodates the spaces in between. Have in future refer to this documentation for many bootstrap components